# Creating a string character by character in Java

Tags: java, hex

So I have created this program:

```
class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String hexa;
        hexa = "";
        int pituus;
        pituus = hexa.length();
        int i = 1;
        char luku;
        char luku2;
        while (i < pituus) {
            luku = hexa.charAt(i);
            luku2 = hexa.charAt(i - 1);
            luku++;
            if (luku == 'G') {
                luku = '0';
                luku2++;
            } else if (luku == ':')
                luku = 'A';

            if (luku2 == '8')
                luku2 = '0';

            System.out.print(luku2);
            System.out.print(luku);
            i += 2;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

As you can propably tell, it prints the original hex string, but adds 1 to every pair of characters, and I want the maximum value of the pairs to be 7F. This program however is only beginning, and to proceed further I need a string with all the characters printed. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you know that you can increment `char` variables like `luku++` will become `B` for if it was previously `A`. You can also use `char nextChar = (char)(luku+1);`. EDIT: OK judging by `luku2++` you know about it, but in that case why you have so many conditions? You can just check char by range like `someChar>='A'` or `someChar<='F'`

Comment: Yeah, I don't actually know, I tried to get some working solution. :D

Comment: Also `if (luku2 == 8)` should probably be `if (luku2 == '8')` (compare characters, not integers). Same about `luku2 = 0;`, try changing it to `luku2 = '0';`

Comment: Good thing you pointed that out, I didn't notice!

Comment: OK, since we made your code clearer, lets focus on your question. To let us understand easier what you want to achieve please please include some examples of input and expected output (with comments about output if that is possible).

Comment: Okay, my input string is 490 char long, so I didn't include it. It is ciphered code and every pair of the characters present a ascii code 0-127. I would like the program to make about 30 similar strings as the one it prints now, first one adding 1 to every value next 2 and so on. Hope you understand.

Comment: I posted example of how you can dynamically generate Strings. Now you just need to also increment `luku2` (you are not doing it anywhere yet) you should be able to generate your similar strings.

Comment: I edited your post and added my try. The increasement happens if `luku == 'G'`

Comment: It seems that you forgot to increment `i` in your loop. This results in infinite loop, which tries to append characters to `StringBuilder` until all available memory will be consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create Strings dynamically you can use StringBuilder. Just append characters to it like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();// builder is empty now

// some logic
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    // for this example we will just add all lower-case 
    // characters to builder
    sb.append(ch);
}
// after all characres are placed in builder 
// lets convert it to string
String alphabet = sb.toString();

// and see what we got
System.out.println(alphabet);
```

Output: dynamically generated alphabet

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: nevermind, I found the issue, I had deleted the argument `i+=2`

Comment: Yes, I saw that and mentioned it in my comment under your question :)